# how to address files by their suffix

Tags: bash, path

I am trying to copy a .nii file (Gabor3.nii) path to a variable but even though the file is found by the `find` command, I can't copy the path to the variable.

```
find . -type f -name "*.nii"
Data= '/$PWD/"*.nii"'
```

output:

```
./Gabor3.nii
./hello.sh: line 21: /$PWD/"*.nii": No such file or directory
```

Comment: `Data=$PWD/*.nii` but it's likely you will have many more follow-up questions around this stuff...

Comment: same problem:   

./hello.sh: line 21: Data=$PWD/*.nii: No such file or directory

Comment: `Data=($(find . -type f -name "*.nii"))` will give you an array of all the matching files.

Comment: On recent `bash` and `zsh` you could use the `**` globbing like `ls **/*.nii`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What went wrong

You show that you're using:

```
Data= '/$PWD/"*.nii"'
```

The space means that the `Data=` parts sets an environment variable `$Data` to an empty string, and then attempts to run `'/$PWD/"*.nii"'`.  The single quotes mean that what is between them is not expanded, and you don't have a directory `/$PWD` (that's a directory name of `$`, `P`, `W`, `D` in the root directory), so the script `"*.nii"` isn't found in it, hence the error message.

#### Using arrays

OK; that's what's wrong.  What's right?

You have a couple of options.  The most reliable is to use an array assignment and shell expansion:

```
Data=( "$PWD"/*.nii )
```

The parentheses (note the absence of spaces before the `(` — that's crucial) makes it an array assignment.  Using shell globbing gives a list of names, preserving spaces etc in the names correctly.  Using double quotes around `"$PWD"` ensures that the expansion is correct even if there are spaces in the current directory name.

You can find out how many files there are in the list with:

```
echo "${#Data[@]}"
```

You can iterate over the list of file names with:

```
for file in "${Data[@]}"
do
    echo "File is [$file]"
    ls -l "$file"
done
```

Note that variable references must be in double quotes for names with spaces to work correctly.  The `"${Data[@]}"` notation has parallels with `"$@"`, which also preserves spaces in the arguments to the command.  There is a `"${Data[*]}"` variant which behaves analogously to `"$*"`, and is of similarly limited value.

If you're worried that there might not be any files with the extension, then use `shopt -s nullglob` to expand the globbing expression into an empty list rather than the unexpanded expression which is the historical default.  You can unset the option with `shopt -u nullglob` if necessary.

#### Alternatives

Alternatives involve things like using command substitution `Data=$(ls "$PWD"/*.nii)`, but this is vastly inferior to using an array unless neither the path in `$PWD` nor the file names contain any spaces, tabs, newlines.  If there is no white space in the names, it works OK; you can iterate over:

```
for file in $Data
do
    echo "No white space [$file]"
    ls -l "$file"
done
```

but this is altogether less satisfactory if there are (or might be) any white space characters around.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive response!

Answer (score 2):

You can use command substitution:

```
Data=$(find . -type f -name "*.nii" -print -quit)
```

To prevent multiline output, the `-quit` option stop searching after the first file was found(unless you're sure only one file will be found or you want to process multiple files).

Comment: thanks for your response, it tried:
data=$(find -type f -name "*.nii" -print -quit)
FUNC=$PWD/$data

But i get /home/Desktop/test13/./Gabor3.nii for FUNC

Do you have any idea how to correct /./ before Gabor3.nii?

Comment: @mohammadreza take a breath and **think** for a minute about where the `.` is coming from, what `$PWD` contains, and the syntax of the `find` command.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to do what you seem to be trying to do with:

```
Data= '/$PWD/"*.nii"'
```

would be:

```
Data="$(ls "$PWD"/*.nii)"
```

Not saying it's the best approach for whatever you want to do next of course, it's probably not...